# What would have happened if Harry was quietly escorted to the Tonks or Weasleys via Muggle ways?

Tags: harry-potter

What would have happened if Order instead of fancifully transporting harry through magical means, thought of transporting Harry through Muggle means (Railway or Road)? Think of the Death Eater's flying in the air waiting for Harry and Harry going through the Muggle World unhindered (possibly disguised). I know one answer would be that Dumbledore wanted Voldemort to establish a firm belief about Snape, but that wouldn't have resulted in Mad-Eye 's death and George's ear loss.

Comment: They were able to observe all entrances and exits to the house. Ergo, the outcome: Harry Splatter.

Comment: @DVK disguising Harry as a neighbour?

Comment: If I'm a death Eater, and I see anyone leaving that house, I swoop in to check it out. Then again, if I'm a Death Eater, I drop something highly unpleasant from a broom into his chimney, which never occurred to them.  Even if he survives, **he no longer has a home**, ergo, no blood protection.

Comment: @DVK Hey wait a minute, I can't find quote to show they were observing all the exists and the entrances.. and they can't see someone leaving the house, because if they did, all the order would be dead as soon as they left the house...

Comment: The fact that they flew on brooms above the house means they saw all the exits. They WERE on Order as soon as they left the house.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From how close the Death Eaters were to Harry and Co. upon leaving the Dursleys we can imagine they would have seen him leave via muggle transport as well. The second that Harry left the protected area surrounding the Dursleys the Death Eaters would have attacked him, and instead of being in the air able to maneuver, he would have been stuck in a car, probably blow up instantly.

> Around him
>   brooms were soaring upward too; the long black tail of a thestral 
>   flicked past. His legs, jammed into the sidecar by Hedwig’s cage and 
>   his rucksack, were already sore and starting to go numb. So great 
>   was his discomfort that he almost forgot to take a last glimpse of 
>   number four, Privet Drive; by the time he looked over the edge of 
>   the sidecar he could no longer tell which one it was. Higher and 
>   higher they climbed into the sky — 
>   And then, out of nowhere, out of nothing, they were surrounded. 
>   At least thirty hooded figures, suspended in midair, formed a 
>   vast circle in the midst of which the Order members had risen,

They were sitting right above his house, and had a birds eye view of the street.

The protection over the house is never clearly defined to say if they could see the house or not, but if they Could see the house then were clearly in possition to see them leave the house, and if they could not see the house, they would know when harry was leaving by the fact that a house just appeared right below them.

This is all besides the point that IF in fact Harry was leaving via car, Snape would have found out and told the Death Eaters anyway. So its a good thing Snape/Dumbledore added a layer of confusion into the mix with multipul people all flying through the air. Their was no way for just Mr Weasly to show up, as the ministry was in on it as well as the order.

Comment: But would they **expect** Harry leaving by a muggle transport?... because I don't think they can see the street directly because if they did, all the order would be dead as soon as they left the house....

Answer (score 5):

I think the fundamental point of this plan is very often missed.

> '... So, we've given a dozen different houses every protection we can throw at them. They all look like they could be the place we're going to hide you, they've all got some connection with the Order: my house, Kingsley's place, Molly's Auntie Muriel's - you get the idea.'
>
> 'Yeah,' said Harry, not entirely truthfully, because he could still spot a gaping hole in the plan.
>
> 'You'll be going to Tonks's parents'. Once you're within the boundaries of the protective enchantments we've put on their house, you'll be able to use a Portkey to The Burrow. Any questions?'
>
> *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* - p.46 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 4, *The Seven Potters*

So, the first point is, that the whole point of the plan is to spirit Harry away to a safe intermediate location, from where he can use a Portkey to The Burrow. They can't put the Portkey within the boundaries of the charm, so the Portkey has to be somewhere else. They've decided to put it in Tonks's parents' house which is very well protected, and they've decided to set up twelve possible locations, so the real location Harry's going to cannot be guessed at. They clearly thought that this was better than having it on a nearby street corner, which cannot be protected.

Another part of the plan is, of course, the decoys. This is an important piece of skulduggery as it divides any opposing forces.

But the final point that I think is overlooked is that the Order believe they've sold Voldemort the dummy.

> 'The one thing we've got on our side is that You-Know-Who doesn't know we're moving you tonight. We've leaked a fake trail to the Ministry: they think you're not leaving until the thirtieth. However, this is You-Know-Who we're dealing with, so we can't just rely on him getting the date wrong; he's bound to have a couple of Death Eaters patrolling the skies in this general area, just in case. ...'
>
> *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* - pp.45-6 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 4, *The Seven Potters*

The Order were very careful to lay this false trail and it very nearly worked. It would have, indeed, if it hadn't been for Snape and Dumbledore.

So to get at the meat of your question: You seem to be saying - well this is all very well Au101, but why not have him go to a more convenient safe house to get the Portkey by stealth? Why not just sneak under the Death Eaters?

Because they believe they've sold Voldemort the dummy. They think they're gonna be up against, at most, one or two contingency Death Eaters, and they would rather have a whole squadron of people, wands out and in a position to fight, so that they can blast through these contingency Death Eaters, if necessary. The decoys also allow them to divide these two contingency Death Eaters among seven, and the Death Eaters will not be able to have a large squad around the Portkey location (because there are twelve possibilities) and the decoys mean any back up that could possibly be coming will not know who to go for.

Not anticipating a vast opposing squad, I take it the Order made the reasonable decision that it was preferable to simply blast through than hope to go unnoticed by the surveillance. A few years ago, me and my mate got stopped in the street by a group of people who were after our phones. Why did we stop, why not leg it? As my mate said, I'd rather they were in front of me. You'd rather be in a position to fight, wands out, confronting the Death Eaters head on, than you would trying to sneak by, not so able to defend yourself from the confines of a Muggle car, or something.

And on that theme, I think the Order reasonably enough chose to go for numbers. They thought they had sold Voldemort the dummy, so they're anticipating one or two Death Eaters. They assembled a vast squad. Nice. If you have a large defence, you are more noticeable. If you want to go unnoticed, you virtually necessarily have to have a smaller defence. And they can't be wands out and ready in a fighting position, they're trying to go unnoticed.